# multi rows of keyboard pattern matching in android

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I am working on a password verifying function.

It has 3 rules:

1. it should not repeat (3 or more consecutive letter abc, efg, etc)
2. it should not repeat 3 or more letter ( e.g aaa, ccc, 111  etc)
3. it should not have 3 or more consecutive keyboard letter ( e.g qwerty, asdf etc)
4. it should not have consecutive multi line letter 
    ( e.g 1 and 2nd row letter in keyboard e.g 1q2w3e4r etc )

I could successfully get the first 2 rules :

```
1.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9!₩£¥@#\\$%^&*()~`\\-=_+\\[\\]{}|:\\\";',\\./<>?\\x21-\\x7e])\\1\\1", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

2.
private boolean validateConsecutiveSeq(String epin) {
    char epinCharArray[] = epin.toCharArray();
    int asciiCode = 0;
    boolean isConSeq = false;
    int previousAsciiCode = 0;
    int numSeqcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < epinCharArray.length; i++) {
        asciiCode = epinCharArray[i];
        if ((previousAsciiCode + 1) == asciiCode) {
            numSeqcount++;
            if (numSeqcount >= 2) {
                isConSeq = true;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            numSeqcount = 0;
        }
        previousAsciiCode = asciiCode;
    }
    return isConSeq;
}
```

Now i am not clear about what pattern i should use for rule no.3 and rule no 4.

Please tell me about how to proceed with pattern matching.
Rule no.4 is is little tricky and confusing for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your case3 and for case4 too something similar might work. I have only used the qwert pattern and not abcd pattern in following code. I am sure you can complete the rest:

```
public static boolean checkCaseThree(String password) {
    String case3 = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    int length = password.length();
    if (length < 3) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 3; i++) {
            String temp = password.substring(i, i + 3);
            if (case3.contains(temp)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```